# Angular App Factory Toaster As Dependency Breaks Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have an angular application that is using Firebase as a backend, and I am trying to inject 'toaster' as a dependency within my authorization app factory.  Here is the start of the app.factory

```
app.factory('principal', ['$rootScope',
'$q', '$http', '$timeout', '$firebaseAuth', "$firebaseObject", '$filter','$firebaseArray', '$state', 'toaster'
function ($rootScope, $q, $http, $timeout, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $filter, $firebaseArray, $state, toaster)
```

With this configuration, the application simply will not load.  I can use 'toaster' inside my controllers but inside of a factory it breaks my application.  I am new to Angular so I don't know if I am missing something or completely off base for adding such a dependency to a factory.

I need a simple toaster pop to alert an incorrect password.  Should I just create a separate controller to handle this?

Comment: I made a typo there is a comma after toaster on line 2.  My application reflects that

Comment: are you talking about angularise version of `toastr`?

Comment: yes Angular toaster, it is an angular.module

Comment: did you injected `toaster` module in your app like `angular.module('app', ['toaster'])`

Comment: yes, toaster works in everything except my factories

Comment: it works for me http://plnkr.co/edit/Lyc9U3?p=preview

Comment: Let me try something similar to your plunk, I will be back

Comment: cool let me know once you reproduce the issue in plunkr

Comment: My loginCtrl toasts work just fine.  In other controllers too.  Still not working in this factory.  I will continue trying things out.

Comment: please reproduce it in plunkr so that i can help you..you might be miss some dependency that is causing an issue

Comment: I will. It may take me 30 minutes or so.  So I don't want to leave you hanging

Comment: All good got it by adding toaster-container to the view.  Thank you for your help

Comment: So you should add that answer..or should I add it?

Comment: You should add it.  I will mark it answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to add `toaster` container on your view so that the message will be shown inside that container.

**Markup**

```
<toaster-container 
toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'animation-class': 'toast-top-center'}">
</toaster-container>
```

Comment: The library I am using is AngularJS toaster